# stagger setInterval multiple elements with same class

Tags: jquery

i have a bunch of images on my page that fade in , delay, and fade out every 5 seconds

it looks a bit odd since all the classes flash in and out at the exact same time.

is there a way to get each interval to execute 500MS after the previous? or perhaps offset each one?

here is the code that flashes them all at the same time.

```
  setInterval(function() {
        $(".some_class").fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
  }, 5000);
```

here is a JSfiddle of them flashing at the same time. http://jsfiddle.net/Vds5f/
thank you.

Comment: updated with a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Vds5f/

Comment: where is the code to fade 1 image at a time?? all images are disappearing at the same time in your fiddle.

Comment: this is what im talking about. im trying to figure out a clean why to make each interval slightly different than one another.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/Vds5f/1/

Answer (score 1):

Working off of Aamir's fiddle, this is what I used for a staggered carousel to switch between images rather than just fade in/out. Should have robust timing against window changes and such (though I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for...)

http://jsfiddle.net/Vds5f/5/

I think it helped consistency to separate the function cycleImages from the setInterval:

```
var $start = +new Date, $ct = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    ++$ct;
    var $frame = (($ct-1)%4+1);
    cycleImages($frame);
}, $i);
```